# CSS concatenation

Tags: wordpress-theming, dynamic-css

I have three divs with class widget-area and the below CSS is for the third widget area.
What does below code means?

```
<div id="supplementary" class="three">
  <div class="widget-area" id="first"></div>
  <div class="widget-area" id="second"></div>
  <div class="widget-area" id="third"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#supplementary.three .widget-area + .widget-area + .widget-area
 {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Can someone is there to help me?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

It selects the `.widget-area`, which comes immediately after two `.widget-area`-s, all contained in a `supplementary.three` (that is, third, fourth, fifth and so on `.widget-areas` contained in a `supplementary.three`). Given your clarified source example, it would be better to rewrite the selector as `#supplementary.three #third.widget-area`.

`margin-right:0` means that there should be no margin to the right of the third (fourth, fifth etc if there would be any) `.widget-area`.